# Shopify - Dawn - Make multicolumn headings searchable

Tags: search, shopify

Is it possible to make the multicolumn section in Shopify's Dawn theme searchable? (or for that matter- any page content that isn't a product)

I would like to be able to search or filter out specific columns. I suppose it would involve somehow hiding irrelevant columns or scrolling to / highlighting the correct column.

Replacing the multicolumns with a collections list is not interesting for me because it would require hundreds of collections.

I don't even know where to begin with this.. I have searched online and in the Shopify app store.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it would need the involvement of javascript, and can be implemented client side.